# SQL How to properly create a summary table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have underlying tables on which the data changes constantly. Every minute or so, I run a stored procedure to summarize the data in those underlying tables into a summary table. The summarization time is very long (~30s) so it does not make sense to have a "summary view." Additionally the summary table is constantly accessed by multiple users, it needs to be quick, responsive, and cannot be down.

To solve this, do the following in the stored procedure:

1. Summarize the data into "new summary table" (this can take as long as it needs because the "current summary table" is serving the needs of the users)
2. Drop the "current summary table"
3. Rename "new summary table" to "current summary table"

My questions are:

1. Is this safe/proper?
2. What happens if a user tries to access the "current summary table" when the summarization procedure is between steps 2 and 3 above?
3. What is the right way to do this? At the end of the day, I just need a summary to always be quickly (this is important) accessible and to be up-to-date (within a minute or so)

Comment: This type of summarization is often scheduled to run once per day in the middle of the night when users are not likely to be using the system.  In some cases, they might be forcibly disconnected.  But there are other solutions as well.

Comment: There are some factors that aren't know here. How long would it take to delete the data in the summary table (by way of a truncate, say) and insert the newly generated summary data?

Answer (score 0):

By using triggers on the details, you can make the summary stay in sync.  For things like average, you need to track sum and count in the summary table as well, so you can recompute average.  Triggers by row might be higher overhead than by all rows of the operation, if you have bulk churn and SQL Server has two flavors of trigger like Oracle.  Inserts might make a summary row or update it, deletes may update or delete the summary row, and updates might change a key and so do both.  Of course, there may be multiple sorts of summary row for any detail row.

Oracle had a materialized view, so maybe SQL Server has that, too.  Oh look, it does!  Google is my friend, so much to remember!  It would be something like a shorthand for the above, at best.

There is the potential for a lot of delay in detail table churn with such triggers.  Regenerating the summary table with a periodic query might suffice for some uses.  A procedure can truncate the previous table for reuse, generate a new table in it, and then in a trans swap the names.  If there is a time stamp in or for the table, the procedure can skip no-change updates.  The lock, disk and CPU overhead for query is often a lot less than for churn.

Some summaries like median are very hard to support except by a view, but it might run fast if indexed (not clustered, sorted not hash index), as queries can be fulfilled right from non-clustered indexes.  Excess indexes slow transactions (churn), so many use replicated tables for reporting, with few, narrow indexes on the parent transaction table and report-oriented indexes on the replicated table.